# An arsenal of tools and know-hows for tackling identification request questions

Tags: discussion, identification-questions

[image: Obligatory Touhou]

*“Awesome! Those unknown materials are waiting for me! I'll have to get my gadgets out then.”* — Nitori Kawashiro.

---

**Step 1:** Read the community wiki below.

**Step 2:** Share your tools and know-hows that trump all the others in at least one instance of answering an [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) question.

**Step 3:** ???

**Step 4:** PROFIT!!!!

Comment: See also: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-can-i-identify-an-anime-using-reverse-image-search?lq=1

Answer (score 8):

### Text

[Google Search](https://www.google.com/) is your obvious choice. You should also utilize [punctuation, symbols and operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433) in your searches to get the most out of what Google Search has to offer. I find myself most frequently using the symbols `"` and, to a lesser extent, `_` and `-`.

> **Note:** Google will customize search results according to a number of different factors. This means that different users will see different results for the same search terms. These factors include, but are not limited to:
>
> - Country and location
> - Language
> - Device
> - Browsing history
> - SafeSearch filter setting
>
> It is impossible to entirely remove the variance in search results because some of the factors are totally outside users' control, e.g. algorithm testing and update lag across data centers.

> **Tip:** Do your search in another language if you're not getting satisfactory results.

> **Exercise:** Try to find the answer to [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19597/looking-for-anime-shown-as-a-comic-strip) by typing `comic single for 16 years` into Google's search box. Now, try `comic "single for 16 years" -site:stackexchange.com`. Which web search query was easier for you to find the answer?

Answer (score 4):

### Images

[**For specific techniques on reverse image searching, see *this post*.**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21618)

[ImgOps](https://imgops.com/) is an extremely useful meta-tool for image operations. It incorporates the following reverse/similar search services: Google, Bing, TinEye, Reddit and Yandex, though all, except Google, perform poorly in my experience. The reverse/similar search services used to include Baidu Shitu as well, but has since been removed.

Baidu's specialty lies in identifying the name of the series from anime screenshots and manga pages, and sometimes even surpasses that of Google.<sup>[[case 1]](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/18647)[[case 2]](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/20324)</sup> Its similar images feature is also often quite accurate. It may be a bit tough to use Baidu Shitu (Shi-tu, not Shit-u) if you don't understand Chinese. Nevertheless, Baidu is a serious contender to Google in the reverse image search department.

I also note some resources linked to by ImgOps that might come in handy at times: iqdb (anime), saucenao (anime+), trace.moe (anime) and ezgif.com. The first two are useful for finding anime wallpapers and artworks, while the last one can be used to break an animated GIF into its individual frames so you could cherry-pick the frames that will return a hit from reverse image search. [trace.moe](https://trace.moe/) is a godsend gifted to us by [soruly](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/22462), which, at times, can even pinpoint the episode and time of an anime a screenshot is taken from.

> **Tip:** If reverse image search didn't turn in anything useful at first, wait a couple of weeks/months and try again. The (full) image could have been indexed by the search engines during this period, so you [might get lucky like me](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/16938) and find it in your subsequent trials.

> **Exercise:** Crop the image from [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/20324) and reverse image search with Baidu. You should get something like this:

> [image: What do I do if Baidu Shitu's suggestions are in Chinese?]

> Although the romaji is given in this case (Chou Majin Eiyuuden Wataru), you should still know how to proceed from here if it weren't given. Copy the Chinese characters enclosed in either of the red boxes added by me, and do a Google search on those characters together with the word "English". It is not clear to me if one would be able to get the name of the other series (Madou King Granzort) without knowledge of Chinese: let's leave that as a challenge.

Answer (score 3):

### Music

The major players in the music identification category are [Shazam](https://www.shazam.com/) and [SoundHound](https://www.soundhound.com/soundhound).

> **Tip:** Try different song segments for identification and remember to check for false positives!

> **Exercise:** Identify the piece of music requested by [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/14380). I recommend using Shazam for this exercise, as SoundHound identified a recording that is not the anime version.

Answer (score 2):

### Videos

Capture a screenshot of the video and do a reverse image search with that, or enclose subtitles, if any, in quotes and do a text search using Google.

> **Tip:** If the video is from YouTube, Vimeo, etc, read the title, description and comments carefully! Chances are, the answer is already written there.

Answer (score 2):

### Characters

**Attribute-based databases**

- [Anime Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/all)
- [Anime Characters Database](https://www.animecharactersdatabase.com/search.php)
- [aniSearch](https://www.anisearch.com/character/index)

**Keyword-based databases**

- [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/character.php)
- [AniList](https://anilist.co/search/characters)

> **Tip:** If your character doesn't show up in the first 100 results, try removing an attribute that you might not be sure of. For example, in the exercise below, the character's eyes appear brownish, but are actually red.

> **Exercise:** Identify the character on the television in [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4767) by searching for a *black- and shoulder-length-haired adult male* on Anime Characters Database.