# Did Someone already proposed compiling Answered ID requests in a meta post?

Tags: discussion, identification-questions

I was just wondering, there is not much use in already answered ID requests and even unanswered ones. Once they are answered they are just left behind.

ID requests is one of the most rapidly increasing tag questions because  new users tend to ask them first aside from **anime recommendations**

And I also noticed that several [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) already has duplicates

I was just thinking of maybe we can possibly compile them in a post here on Anime.SE and maybe use them as one of those [arsenal of tools](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/an-arsenal-of-tools-and-know-hows-for-tackling-identification-request-questions?s=1%7C0.4279) for tackling ID- requests.

Maybe we can format it like Q and A style where a single answer would consist of a certain tag with its corresponding ID requests like this :

---

Anime Title/tag
[blue-gender](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blue-gender).

Answered ID requests:

[what-is-this-anime-movie-similar-to-appleseed](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20781/what-is-this-anime-movie-similar-to-appleseed?s=7%7C0.1586)

[anime-in-space-with-blonde-short-hair-girl-and-brown-haired-guy](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29364/anime-in-space-with-blonde-short-hair-girl-and-brown-haired-guy/29365?s=5%7C0.2498#29365)

[need-help-identifying-anime-with-people-getting-into-robots-and-fighting-aliens](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29081/need-help-identifying-anime-with-people-getting-into-robots-and-fighting-aliens/29085?s=4%7C0.2515#29085)

[looking-for-old-war-anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/30165/looking-for-old-war-anime/30179#30179)

---

suggestions for formatting would be discussed and accepted by everyone like in this post in meta

[You want recommendations? Here's a list of them](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/you-want-recommendations-heres-a-list-of-them?s=7%7C0.1449)

It would be beneficial not only to the site but also to New users asking help identifying an anime title they don't remember. We can ask them to browse this **compilation** because maybe there is already an answer in this compilation.

And It could be much easier to answer ID-Requests.

Also, I would like to add that I ***Really*** like answering ID-Requests. Why? Its because in this I discover new and not so old but good anime that would add to my watch list.

This is just a proposal but if this is Approved I would be one of those SO much-willing to help. :)

I really hope you can consider this proposal.

Comment: I agree that answered id requests are basically worthless--we had seven, [one](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/28919/7579) [two](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6608/7579) [three](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/7856/7579) [four](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/14173/7579) [five](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19943/7579) [six](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/28919/7579) [seven](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/14186/7579) id requests looking for Shinzo, all with almost entirely different details. However, I don't think this proposal will help that problem...

Comment: ...because they had almost entirely different details. I don't think reading old id requests will help much with answering new ones. And if you do need to read old ones, using the search bar or Google with site:http://anime.stackexchange.com is a more efficient way to find possibly relevant ones. Plus, this would be a *ton* of work; we have 2,111 id requests, and only 276 are unanswered. So it's a ton of work for marginal gains; even if doing this would give us a magic ring that would answer every id request to ever come to the site, it's still marginal gains.

Comment: @Torisuda But If I want to still do this even by myself. (really love to organize things) would that still be rejected? I'll start as soon as possible if you would let me :) 2,000 ID requests isnt that big if your willing to do this. I'm not saying your _Not_ , I understand that not all of us have that much time to spend here in Anime.SE (except for Mods I guess) but if I spend and allot time each day doing this. I think I can manage. Please :)

Comment: If you just really, really want to do this on your own, nothing is stopping you. I personally don't think it's a useful project for the site, as Google is already a better way to find information for answering id requests. It's also not how I would choose to spend my time. But maybe other people in the community disagree with me. Even if the community doesn't think it's useful, you can still make e.g. a GitHub repo containing a Markdown doc containing your compilation of 2000 id request answers, and maintain it yourself as new answers come in.

Comment: @Torisuda hmmmm on another site or a website or blog maybe? I can also make that as an advertisement for Anime.SE maybe? I would consider your comment.

Comment: I would wait for someone else's input before you do anything. This meta question has only been viewed 13 times. It's not like I have the final say on site policy. Wait a few days and someone else a chance to speak up.

Comment: I think you've found a very inefficient way to explore new anime. Have you tried browsing through user recommendations of the anime you already know and like? [(Example)](http://myanimelist.net/anime/5114/Fullmetal_Alchemist__Brotherhood/userrecs)

Comment: Additionally, ID requests may be removed completely from the site (this is not guaranteed, but such a possibility is very real) and in that case, advertisement of A&M through off-topic question type would become misleading.

Comment: Aside from everything, [please join us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) where we can discuss everything in real time, probably with more users than here, and talk on other topics. Recommendations are what we do in chat, too.

Comment: It kind of sounds like a custom 20Qs is what you want http://en.akinator.com/

Answer (score 7):

I'll go ahead and compile my comments into a real answer so that people can up- or downvote it.

It's true that answered id requests are basically worthless. This is one of the many reasons I don't think having id requests adds much to the site. For example, we had seven id requests looking for Shinzo—that's [one](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/28919/7579) [two](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6608/7579) [three](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/7856/7579) [four](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/14173/7579) [five](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19943/7579) [six](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/28919/7579) [seven](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/14186/7579). Clearly the previously answered questions weren't helping anyone.

However, I don't think this proposal is an answer to that problem. The details the OPs remembered on each of those seven questions are different enough that the OP probably never would have realized the other six questions were looking for the same show.

I also don't think this proposal will be particularly helpful to people answering id requests. Google is an amazingly powerful tool for searching information, and not just information on our site. Chances are, if you can find the answer by browsing a giant list of previously answered id requests, you can find it more easily using Google. And if you *do* think that looking at previously answered id requests will help you, we have a search bar, which I used to find those seven questions looking for Shinzo. (I originally thought it was five, but the search turned up a couple I hadn't known about.) You can also use Google for that: do a search with `site:http://anime.stackexchange.com`. For instance, I found the Shinzo identification requests again by doing a search for `shinzo "identification request" site:http://anime.stackexchange.com` on Google.

I think the gains here will be marginal. If it were a small amount of work, it might still be worth doing, but it won't be a small amount of work; it will be gargantuan. We have over 2,000 identification request questions, with about 280 of them unanswered. So members of the site will have to go through the remaining ~1720 id requests, see what the answer turned out to be, then go to another page with an index of anime and manga, find the one which answered the id request, and edit the entry to add a link to the question. That's for the ones which actually have accepted answers; a bunch of them have answers which aren't accepted, because the OP ran off. A bunch also have answers in comment threads. So you have to read every piece of text on the page to make sure there isn't an answer buried in some comment thread underneath a wrong answer. And then we need people to keep doing this for every single new id request that gets answered.

We don't actually have that many people on this site doing maintenance and review tasks. During the image-only id request cleanup, I kept seeing the same eleven or twelve names on all the close votes. So there's a shortage of workers even potentially willing to take on this gargantuan task.

---

Of course, if you just really really want to do this, regardless of the community's opinion, there's nothing stopping you. You can even do it offsite somewhere, like on GitHub or a blog, where you control the whole process. However, I would ask you not to promote Anime and Manga.SE as a site for identification requests; we already get plenty.

(Digression: recently, I've been trying to find an alternative site where we can direct id requests, and I think I've stumbled on the reason why we get so many: because none of the other obvious sites (Reddit, Quora, Yahoo Answers, MyAnimeList, etc.) seem to do id requests. The ones I did see on those sites had been either completely ignored or sloppily answered with something that was obviously wrong. By contrast, a certain contingent of users here leap to answer id requests, and will levy the full force of their usually considerable research skills to find the answer. Thus, our legend spreads throughout the Internet as a magical site that can find "Evangelion" given the description "I watched it when I was young, there was this nerdy guy in a white shirt and this girl with red hair and in one episode they went to a hot spring".)

---

I'll end this answer with some personal advice, which you are free to take or ignore. It might sound harsh, but it's meant to be helpful, so read it in that spirit.

You seem to be extremely excited about participating on Anime and Manga. That's good! We need people who are excited to participate. At the same time, I've noticed you doing some things, especially in the review process, that aren't productive or go against the policies of SE in general or Anime and Manga in particular. One of these came up in [Is there a meta post here on Anime.SE that explains user bans?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2749/7579). I think you're getting too excited and rushing ahead to do things without finding out beforehand whether your actions are welcome or useful.

I recommend that you instead take your time getting acclimated to the site. Ask and answer questions instead of worrying too much about reviewing or side projects. Read the best questions and answers the site has to offer, and learn from them what a good question and a good answer look like. I think we have some of the most amazing posts on the entire SE network, and I learned a lot about what a good post looks like from reading them. Go to chat, if you want, and get other people's opinions. Doing this will also let you identify real problems that the community has, and come up with solutions that benefit everyone. SE is a community effort. Everyone builds and maintains the site together, and each site has a different culture. To make valuable contributions, you should make an effort to understand that culture.

Comment: _I think you're getting too excited and rushing ahead to do things without **finding out beforehand whether your actions are welcome or useful.**_ - Don't you think this might be the reason **WHY** I posted here in meta first?

Comment: @MykAgustin Yes, coming here was a good first step. But that sentence you quoted was not just about this single proposal; it was about a pattern of behavior I've seen from you that comes from your newness to SE. I am counseling you to first master the core of SE, recognizing and writing great posts, and spend some time to build reputation, both the fake Internet points kind and actual reputation among other members of the community. This will give you knowledge and perspective to address problems the site faces and propose solutions to them.